# Can't read bytes from file PHP

Tags: php, file-io, byte

I have a problem, even I use "rb" in fopen(), it doesn't read bytes. For example when in file were digits 1234 or letters. I had got the same as in file.

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

class Archivator 
{
    public function readFile($file)
    {
        $stream = fopen($file, "rb");
        while ($byteStr = fread($stream, 1)){
            var_dump($byteStr);
            echo $byteStr."\n";
        }
    }
}

$arch = new Archivator();
$arch->readFile('d:\\ok\\vas.txt');

$x=fgets(STDIN);
```

Comment: display_errors on?  No error I see from this, is this the entire code?  Other than the fact that you read one byte at a time, which I believe would be quite inefficient.

Comment: nope, there's no errors. it's show one symbol. i know about inefficient, i'll fix it later

Comment: Does file_get_contents() return the same symbol?

Comment: @Devon yeap, everything is the same.

Comment: So what is in that file?  Try doing `file_put_contents($file, '1234'); file_get_contents($file);`.  That'll prove that it is your file that is the problem.

Comment: @Devon Yes, I have done it, everything is the same. how can i fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by everything is the same?

Comment: @Devon, I mean that, if put there 1234, I get 1234.

Comment: @tgg132: so what is the problem?

Comment: @BenoitEsnard  
 
I need to read a byte, not a symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what are you up to, but `fread` will read a character as string. If you want to display its byte value (ASCII) you can use `ord` and optionally `dechex`:

```
while ($char = fread($stream, 1)){
    printf("Byte value of '%s' is %d (%s hex)\n", $char, ord($char), dechex(ord($char)));
}
```

Also, don't forget to close the file when you're done with `fclose($stream)`.